# What does $config mean

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a wordpress blog.I had a Tutorial but i cant uderstand that what does `$config['pathSrcInclude']` mean?  As in:

```
include_once($config['pathSrcInclude']."common.inc.php");
```

I am getting an error like this

> /Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'src/common.inc.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php') in /home/content/66/8073766/html/thinkblogger.com/popups/photos.php on line 8

Please anyone know the reason behind it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
$config['pathSrcInclude']
```

is looking in an array called $config for the element pathSrcInclude

From what i'm seeing the line you have shown is trying to include a file but its not in the location submitted.

Based on the error you are getting the array element above contains this string: "src/"

So what that line is actually doing is looking for this:

```
include_once("src/common.inc.php");
```

Which should be the location of a file, but from the looks of your error the file isn't there.

Hope this helps,
Chris

Comment: But the file is present there I am sure about that

Comment: @Zain Are you sure you're working in the directory above `src`? what do you get if you `echo getcwd();`?

Comment: Well if you are working from `src`, the line should be `include_once("common.inc.php");`

Comment: If the file is indeed there and accessible then changing it to this should work: include_once("src/common.inc.php");

Comment: You are workiing from a PHP file in this directory:
thinkblogger.com/popups/
so you are saying that your file is here:
thinkblogger.com/popups/src/
I'd wager your file might actually be here:
thinkblogger.com/src

Comment: what do you get if you add this line immediately above the `include_once` call? `echo 'file '.((file_exists($config['pathSrcInclude']."common.inc.php")) ? 'exists' : 'does not exist').'; file '.((is_readable($config['pathSrcInclude']."common.inc.php")) ? 'is' : 'is not').' readable';`

Comment: Try what Dave Random says and then try changing the line to this:  
include_once("../src/common.inc.php");
If this works then you are in the wrong directory

Answer (score 0):

By what your telling, the problem seems to be the path for the file... it's wrong and PHP generates a **WARNING** telling you just that!

`$config` seems to be and array of configuration values, and the `pathSrcInclude` should contaion the right path for the file that you are trying to include.

Answer (score 0):

What Chris Cummings said, plus, check your permissions on that file.

Make sure it is accessible by scripts (probably CHMOD 0755).